# Access local storage inside a groovy script

Tags: groovy, local-storage

I have to write a groovy script through application composer on a particular action. There is a need to store few values of data at browser level so that it would be used in the next process. 
Can we access local storage and put values from a groovy script? Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

groovy runs on server side, we can't run groovy script in the browser. you need to use Javascript  in this case.